# How many force.com sites can an organisation have?

Tags: force.com, force.com-sites

We're working with a potential customer who is using force.com's sites feature to host public facing websites. From what I can find, there seems to be a limit of 25 sites for the Unlimited account level (which they use currently): https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/sites_limits.htm

Some discussions (http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Force-com-Sites-Site-com/Sites-Price-amp-Availability/m-p/183240/highlight/true#M2766) I've read indicate that it's not possible to increase this limit. Can anyone confirm if this is the case (or not)?

I'm not able to find pricing for additional sites anywhere, either - if you have managed to increase your limit, how much did it cost?

Comment: Well, you have the (former) PM for Sites saying it's not possible on that thread, so that's not a good sign. I'd be kind of surprised if this was not a black-tabbable setting, since you can't imagine there would be much marginal cost (if any) to SFDC allowing more configured Sites against one instance. Please let us know what you find out. As a workaround, it seems likely you could find something suitable using a URLRewriter implementation - they work well.

Comment: Thanks, jkray - I hadn't heard of the 'black tab' before. Please see my response to Ryan's answer - we're  not recommending that they increase the site limit, we're actually trying to convince them to do something different.

Comment: When you suggest 'URLRewriter' implementation - am I right in thinking you mean effectively serving the pages for multiple different websites from what is a single site configured in force.com? I'd be hesitant to suggest this, seeing as we're trying to simplify their process for deploying new sites, and it's important that the sites are not seen to be linked - so redirect responses would be out of the question, for instance.

Comment: I find the urlRewriter also to take quite some time to work, and it fails when you have a high need for parameter usage.

Comment: @Beejamin perhaps something like that, although if you want thorough suggestions you'll need to provide a lot more detail on what the actual customer problem/goal is.

Comment: Since SF people read these, how about giving the platform a lot more revenue opportunities by offering a la carte limit exceptions?  You do this already on api calls, data storage, etc.  Why not on extra sites, tabs, etc where people run into similar limits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

25 is the limit for EE and UE organizations.

What is your use case for needing more than 25?

Comment: To be honest, our position is that they're using force.com for things it's not designed to do (hosting separate sites for many different 'sub-brands' the company has). We're in the process of recommending a different approach, and the apparently hard-limit of 25 is going to be a pretty compelling reason to change soon (they could well need 100+ sites over the next couple of years).

Answer (score 1):

We have used Force.com Sites in lot of places for various enterprise implementation, The 25 Sites is good enough in my experience. In fact in one site you can create lot of pages. It is not like one site = 1 web page

Comment: Please see my response to Ryan Guest's answer...

Answer (score 1):

We have some clients that wants to use force as a platform for many apps and they are in lot of countries, so 25 sites is nothing compare with what they are expecting to do.

I posted the following idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ktX3AAI. I will appreciate if you can promote it.

Thanks on advance!